# Solving the eigenvalue system

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

$Au_{m,n}+Bu_{m-10,n-10}+Cu_{m+10,n+10}+Du_{m,n-10}+Eu_{m-10,n}=\lambda u_{m,n}$

where $A=0.01(m^2+n^2),\quad B=0.1(m+n),\quad C=0.1(m-n),\quad D=0.1 m, \quad E=0.1 n$. and $m,n$ range from $[-50,50]$. My problem is hhow to transform the equation into a matrix form.

Comment: This does not seem to be a Mathematica-specific question. How would one solve this outside of Mathematica ?

Comment: This problem is block-diagonal modulo 10: all indices $m$ that end in "1" are coupled only among each other, and all that end in "2" are coupled only among each other, etc., and the same for $n$. You can therefore set up 100 sub-problems with indices $\{m,n\}$ all ending the same way. This may simplify the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You can set this equation into a SparseArray with

```
s = 50;
U = Table[Subscript[u, m, n], {m, -s, s}, {n, -s, s}] // Flatten;
X = SparseArray[{{m_,m_,n_,n_}->((m-s-1)^2+(n-s-1)^2)/100,
                 {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/;m1==m-10&&n1==n-10->((m-s-1)+(n-s-1))/10,
                 {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/;m1==m+10&&n1==n+10->((m-s-1)-(n-s-1))/10,
                 {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/;m1==m&&n1==n-10->(m-s-1)/10,
                 {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/;m1==m-10&&n1==n->(n-s-1)/10},
                {2s+1,2s+1,2s+1,2s+1}] //ArrayFlatten;
```

This gets you a list of $(2s+1)^2$ equations:

```
Thread[X.U == \[Lambda] U]
(* list of equations *)
```

The eigensystem is then

```
Eigensystem[N[X]]
```

If you want periodic boundary conditions expressed by the rollover function `f`:

```
s = 50;
U = Table[Subscript[u, m, n], {m, -s, s}, {n, -s, s}] // Flatten;
f[a_] = Mod[a, 2s+1, -s];
X = SparseArray[{{m_,m_,n_,n_}->((m-s-1)^2+(n-s-1)^2)/100,
      {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/; f[m1-m]==-10 && f[n1-n]==-10 ->((m-s-1)+(n-s-1))/10,
      {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/; f[m1-m]==+10 && f[n1-n]==+10 ->((m-s-1)-(n-s-1))/10,
      {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/; f[m1-m]==0   && f[n1-n]==-10 ->(m-s-1)/10,
      {m_,m1_,n_,n1_}/; f[m1-m]==-10 && f[n1-n]==0   ->(n-s-1)/10},
     {2s+1,2s+1,2s+1,2s+1}]//ArrayFlatten;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, if I want to consider the periodic  boundary condition, how do I improve the code? i.e., if $m-10<-(2s+1)$, we need $m-10\rightarrow m-10+(2s+1)$ .

Comment: So you want $m=-51$ to be equal to $m=+50$? Or do you rather want $m=-50$ to be equal to $m=+50$? It makes a big difference how precisely you're doing the periodic connection.

Comment: eg., for $s=50$, the  range $m$ is $[-101,101]$, but for $m=-101$, $m-10=-111$, which has exceeded the range, so I need to consider the periodic boundary condition that make $m-10=-111$ be $-111+202=91$. How should I do?

Comment: @yunshi: for $s=50$, the range is $m\in[-50,50]$. For $m=-50$ you then find $m-10=-60\mapsto-60+101=41$ using the `Mod` function with offset: `f[a_]=Mod[a,2s+1,-s]`. Try: `s=50;f[a_]=Mod[a,2s+1,-s];Table[f[a],{a,-60,60}]`